# mediawiki instance served by apache on specific domain

Tags: apache, dns, mediawiki, virtualhost

So, I use MediaWiki, hosted by Apache (wiki dir is in /var/www/html/wiki).

I have my domain www.my-domain.com which is redirected through apache virtual host to port 8080 for some nodejs app.

I have now tried to set up my wiki to be served on http://wiki.my-domain.com

In my DNS records i have both www and wiki domains redirected to same server.

First I tried to make apache virtual host to handle domain request:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName my-domain.com
    ServerAlias wiki.my-domain.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/wiki

</VirtualHost>
```

However if I tried to connect to **wiki.my-domain.com** or **wiki.my-domain.com/wiki** I got the message that the page doesn't exists.

I went to check my wiki's **LocalSetting.php** 
and I tried editing this line:

```
## If i changed value to this, it didn't worked
$wgServer = "http://wiki.my-domain.com";
## If i set value to this, it was working
$wgServer = "http://my-server-IP";
```

However, if i set wgServer to my server IP, whenever i write **http://wiki.my-domain.com**, i get redirected to **http://my-IP/wiki** instead of staying on domain name

I would appreciate the help on how to properly set up my wiki's or apache's settings to properly host my wiki on my domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem:
$wgScript was set to:

> $wgScript="/wiki"

and needs to be set to:

> $wgScript=""

since Apache was redirecting the domain already to my /wiki folder, there was no need for script to also redirect it there and this was causing problems.